# Is there any concise proof that if cumulative distribution functions are equal than probability distributions are equal?

Tags: probability

Is there any concise proof that if cumulative distribution functions are equal than probability distributions are equal? Would pi-lambda theorem be of any help here?

$$
F_{\mu} =F_{\nu}
$$
$$
\mu(A)=\nu(A) $$ $$ for A \in B(\Bbb R^n)
$$

Comment: Equality of cumulative distribution functions says that the measures agree on sets of a certain form. You should try checking if those sets form a $\pi$-system and if the sets on which the measures agree is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: There is a quick proof using the Carathéodory Extension Theorem.